# Checking if DataRow cell partially contains string

Tags: c#, foreach, system.data

I need to eliminate all rows that contain either `string notUsed` or `string notUsed2`, where a particular identity is 2.

I'm using a foreach loop to accomplish this, prior to appending any of my data to a stringbuilder.

I would have chosen a method like so:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        int auth = (int)dr[0];
        if (auth == 2) continue;
        string notUsed = "NO LONGER USED";
        string notUsed2 = "NO LONGER IN USE";

        if (dr.Cells[3].ToString().Contains(string)notUsed)
        {
            dr.Delete();
        }
        else
        {
            if (dr.Cells[3].ToString().Contains(string)notUsed2)
            {
                dr.Delete();
            }
        }
    }
```

However, the above is... utterly wrong. It seems logical to me, but I don't quite understand how to form that method in a way that C# understands.

Comment: Just remove `string` from Contains like: `if (dr[3].ToString().Contains(notUsed))`. Also you are trying to modify the collection in a `foreach` loop by deleting the rows. It will raise the exception. Use a `for` loop, better if you use it in reverse order

Comment: @Habib but what do I use in place of `Cells` ?

Comment: just remove `Cells` it should be `dr[3]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should

- Remove `Cells` as it is not a property of `DataRow` instead use
  `dr[3]`.
- Remove `string` from Contains so your check should be like: `if (dr[3].ToString().Contains(notUsed))`
- You are modifying the collection inside a `foreach` loop, by deleting the row. You should use `for`  loop backward.

Like:

```
for (int i = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    DataRow dr = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i];
    int auth = (int)dr[0];
    if (auth == 2) continue;
    string notUsed = "NO LONGER USED";
    string notUsed2 = "NO LONGER IN USE";

    if (dr[3].ToString().Contains(notUsed))
    {
        dr.Delete();
    }
    else
    {
        if (dr[3].ToString().Contains(notUsed2))
        {
            dr.Delete();
        }
    }
}
```

**You can also use [LINQ to DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386977(v=vs.110).aspx)** and get a new `DataTable` like:

```
DataTable newDataTAble = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                            .Where(r => !r.Field<string>(3).Contains(notUsed) &&
                                        r.Field<string>(3).Contains(notUsed2))
                            .CopyToDataTable();
```